# C# List with Unique Entries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list

I have a list like this,

```
List A

ItemNum                  FileName

001                      A.txt,B.txt,A.txt,B.txt
002                      A.txt,C.txt,A.txt,C.txt
```

I need to make a list like this.

```
ItemNum                  FileName

001                      A.txt,B.txt
002                      A.txt,C.txt
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @Deva, did any of these answer your question? If so, could you mark it as accepted, or add more detail as to what else you need?

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitive, in a method format:

```
public List<string> ToDistinct(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    List<string> unique = new List<string>();

    foreach (string s in input)
    {
        List<string> files = s.Split(',').ToList();
        unique.Add(String.Join(",", files.Distinct()));
    }

    return unique;
}
```

Here's a console method that displays the output like you have above and you can tweak it if you like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> input = new List<string>{"A.txt,B.txt,A.txt,B.txt", "A.txt,C.txt,A.txt,C.txt"};

    //Display Input
    Console.WriteLine("Input");
    Console.WriteLine("ItemNum                  FileNames");
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" {0,-23:000}{1}", i + 1, input[i]));
    }

    //Build the Unique List
    List<string> unique = new List<string>();

    foreach (string s in input)
    {
        List<string> files = s.Split(',').ToList();
        unique.Add(String.Join(",", files.Distinct()));
    }

    //Display Output
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Output");
    Console.WriteLine("ItemNum                  FileNames");
    for(int i = 0; i < unique.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" {0,-23:000}{1}", i + 1, unique[i]));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that you convert the FileName's to a `List<string>`, then all you need is this:

```
listA.ForEach(x => x.FileNames = x.FileNames.Distinct().ToList());
```

If there is no specific reason why you're storing what is - for all intents - a list in a string.. why not store it as one? `List<string>` will allow you to add and remove as you see fit.

Comment: Hmmm.... he didn't seem to want to overwrite listA, nor are his FileNames broken out into a List<string>. I think OP is asking how to do this. If you want a one liner, this would be more appropriate: `List<string> listB = (from x in listA select String.Join(",", x.Split(',').Distinct())).ToList();`

Comment: @Ehryk I am aware of that, however my suggestion makes working with this list of filenames simple throughout the application. Would you consider it good practise to be Splitting this string up everywhere you needed to check individual items? That's what a List is for.. hence why I suggested the OP convert it to a List.

Comment: Right, but it is somewhat unfair to answer a question with 'change your architecture.' I agree you would not want to split it out every time, but what if this is ubiquitous through a large application and converting a basic `List<string>` to a `List<Item>` where each item is defined as `class Item{int ItemNum;List<string> FileNames;}` could be entirely impractical. I understand what you mean now; but I didn't upon casual reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(new Item("001", "A.txt,B.txt,A.txt,B.txt"));
list.Add(new Item("002", "A.txt,C.txt,A.txt,C.txt"));
var newList = from l in list
              select new Item() { ItemNum = l.ItemNum, 
                                  FileName = string.Join(",", l.FileName.Split(',').Distinct()) };
```